# Unable to get jsondata in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3

Here i need to check the value for key `img_type` if it is 1 then i need to get the key value pair of `img_file` if not 2 then i need to get the key value pair `img_url` but i got stuck here while checking the value i am getting error with this code can anyone help me how to implement this ?

```
{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "banner1",
        "status": "1",
        "display_from": null,
        "display_to": null,
        "img_type": "1",
        "img_file": "https://192.168.1.11/magento2/pub/media/ewl_bannerslider/slides/5.jpg",
        "img_url": "",
        "img_title": "banner1",
        "img_alt": "banner1",
        "url": "",
        "is_open_url_in_new_window": "1",
        "is_add_nofollow_to_url": "1"
},
{
        "id": "5",
        "name": "banner5",
        "status": "1",
        "display_from": null,
        "display_to": null,
        "img_type": "2",
        "img_file": "https://192.168.1.11/magento2/pub/media/ewl_bannerslider/slides/",
        "img_url": "https://www.dtelepathy.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Technique-for-Faster-Web-Development.jpg",
        "img_title": "",
        "img_alt": "",
        "url": "",
        "is_open_url_in_new_window": "1",
        "is_add_nofollow_to_url": "1"
}

func bannerDownloadJsonWithURL(){
        let url = URL(string: bannerUrl)!
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil { print(error!); return }
            do {
                if let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [[String:Any]] {
                    for item in jsonObj {
                        if let itemDict = item as [String:Any]! {
                            for item in itemDict {
                                if item.key["img_type"] == 1 {

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: add error code please for better understanding and in which line you are getting this error

Comment: if item.key["img_type"] == 1 in this line i am getting error @NupurGupta

Comment: cannot subscript a value of type 'String' with an index of type 'String' this is the error @NupurGupta

Comment: All parameter look like string value and you are comparing Int value in If condition.  Try like  if item.key["img_type"] == "1".

Comment: the same error above mentioned still continues @AmitKumarVashishtha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use like below :

```
if let itemDict = item as [String:Any]! {
    if let imgTypeString = itemDict["img_type"] as? String, let imgType = Int(imgTypeString) {
        if imgType == 1 {
            print("img_file", itemDict["img_file"])
        } else if imgType == 2 {
            print("img_url", itemDict["img_url"])
        }
    } else {
        print("Unable to parse img_type")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`item.key["img_type"]` is an incorrect way to get value from key. Either use `item["img_type"]` to get value of `item.objectForKey("img_type")`.

```
if let itemDict = item as [String:Any]!
{
     for item in itemDict 
     {
         let diction = item as [String:Any]!
         let imageType = diction["img_type"] as! String
         if Int(imageType) == 1  
         {
         }
     }
}
```

Also check for data type of `img_type` value

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnkBm.png after changing as mentioned by you still the error continues as mentioned in image